# naming a new environment

Tags: environments

I'm using the `listings` package and several others; I'm formatting code in both Scheme and Ocaml. I'd like to write something compact to say "here's some Scheme code" or "here's some Ocaml code". So following advice I found elsewhere on tex-stackexchange, I tried this

```
\lstnewenvironment{O} {\lstset{language=[CS17]Ocaml}}{}
```

where "[CS017]Ocaml" is a language that I've defined. I got an error that the environment "O" was already defined. So I called it "OC" instead, and everything worked.

My question: Is there some way other than trial and error (or reading every bit of source code for every package I'm using) to know which environments have already been defined?

Comment: If you don't want to use already used and don't want to read documentation, I'd suggest to use what could be no so probable names. As an example, `\lstnewenvironment{JohnO}`. ;-)

Comment: The control sequence `\O` is taken, so you're not allowed to name `O` an environment. Finding the legal names is not easy: they depend on what packages you load. Why not `Ocaml`?

Comment: What I really wanted was an `\ocaml{ ... }` macro, but that required putting the content of a `lstlisting` into an argument, and that's not allowed either. So to keep the commonly-used things short, I was hoping to use "O"; `OC` was a compromise. What I was hoping for here was something like `\printenvnames` that'd spit the names of all currently-defined environments into my document; apparently that doesn't exist.

Comment: One more reason not to use "ocaml": I've already used it as a name for a kind of "comment" in the `comments` package.